# Automatic task execution on google app engine development server (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task

The docs for the python dev server say this about running tasks:

> When your app is running in the
>   development server, task queues are
>   not processed automatically. Instead,
>   task queues accrue tasks which you can
>   examine and execute from the developer
>   console...

But the release notes for version 1.3.4 of the python sdk (which I am using) say:

> Auto task execution is now enabled in
>   the dev_appserver. To turn this off
>   use the flag --disable_task_running.

So maybe the docs are a little behind, right? Except when I go to "http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/tasks?queue=default", I see this:

> Tasks will not run automatically. Push the 'Run' button to execute each task.

Can tasks be run automatically or not? If so, what is the trick?

Comment: Hey David, I solved the problem by switching to python 2.5.  I'm using your gaesessions, btw.  Quite nice. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the problem was that I was running the dev server with python 2.6 instead of 2.5.  When using 2.5, everything worked.

Comment: Nice catch.  I wish dev_appserver would check the Python version and warn you if you ran it on anything but a 2.5.x flavor.