# Google App Engine Development Task Queue Not Running

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel, djangoappengine

I'm adding Tasks to my development default task queue like so...

```
task = Task(params={'id':'foo','name':'bar'},
    countdown=0,
    url = '/foobar',
)
task.add()
```

But my Tasks just sit in the default queue and don't execute. If I run them manually by going to `/_ah/admin/tasks?queue=default` and clicking the "Run" button everything seems to go fine--Queued tasks disappear from Queue and `/foobar` is accessed successfully.

Am I missing something here? Seems like this should "just work".

**NOTE:** It may be pertinent that I'm using Django + Django Nonrel + DjangoAppEngine--not their Task interface, but for views, templates, models, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115053/automatic-task-execution-on-google-app-engine-development-server-python), automatic task execution only works if you're running Python 2.5. Are you running something higher?

Failing that, check to make sure you're using at least version 1.3.4 of the SDK, and you're not passing --disable_task_running to dev_appserver.py.